# How to make editor active in intellij plugin development?

Tags: intellij-idea, plugins, action

I'm trying to write plugin for Intellij Idea. I need make some manipulations for editors, for example, navigate to certain editor, make it active.
I can get all editors this way: `FileEditor[] editors = FileEditorManager.getInstance(e.getProject()).getAllEditors();`
So how can I navigate, for example, to first editor `editors[0]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

`FileEditorManager.getInstance(project).openFile(editors[0].getFile(), true, true)`

Comment: Maybe I have different version, but `FileEditor` doesn't have method `getFile()`. To get `VirtualFile` I used `FileEditorManager.getInstance(e.getProject()).getOpenFiles()`, so it works this way.

Comment: I think this method was introduced in IntelliJ IDEA 2017.3.